# Has Oracle removed Sun net.ftp classes?

Tags: java, apache, ftp, sun, deprecated

I have an older project that uses the `sun.net.ftp.FtpClient` class to download a file from an ftp server. It appears that Oracle has finally removed this unsupported/deprecated feature from Java. Any suggestions on what should be used to replace it? I was considering `org.apache` classes but I have never used them. The best solution would be the simplest.

Comment: What makes you think Oracle removed those classes? Even though you should avoid using sun.* classes (it's clearly a bad practice) i'd be surprised if Sun/Oracle actually removed those. What JDK version do you use?

Comment: Yes, I know it is a bad practice. I am just trying to keep this barely used project working until I can kill it. My JDK is still j6u20 and I have a test machine running the j6u21 JRE. Perhaps it was renamed to oracle.net.ftp?

Comment: Even with the update 21 JDK it is still broke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dependending on your requirements i'd recommend to use either the FTP client provided by [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) or [edtFTP/j](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpj/).

Comment: I ended up using the org.apache.commons.net package as it is looks to be well supported and pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

## [finj - FTP Client for Java Apps](http://finj.sourceforge.net/)

---

### What is finj ?

Sun provides 
a FTP client written in Java as part of the standard classes. 
Unfortunately, since the `sun.net.ftp.*` classes are not 
part of the `java.*` packages, neither the source code 
nor a complete API are available.

The goal of this project is to provide to developers a complete, 
*well designed*, programmatically controllable Open-Source 
**FTP client written in the Java language**. `finj` then simply stands for 'FTP in Java'.

---

It provides an API similar to `sun.net.ftp.FtpClient` so that you can use it without changing your code very much.